# When I try to make json by using npm init it gives the follow ing message

Tags: node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dw8K.png)

Error of installing json

Comment: Have you installed Node.JS?

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed nodejs in your system. To check whether it has been installed or not run these two commands in terminal.

```bash
node -v
npm -v
```

If they give error like npm or node is not recognised as internal or external command. Then that it means node is not installed. First install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) then run `npm init` command. NPM gets installed automatically with node.